# Run a command as su - through ssh through a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, su

Hi so basicly what I am trying to do is run a script that is located on the remote server as root by running su - before running the script.

I need to run the script after running the command su - otherwise it wont run. And at the state that the server will be sudo isnt installed yet.

Right now I have ssh -t $USERNAME@$IP "su - && /home/$USERNAME/firstboot/firstboot.sh" but it connects me as su - on the remote server but dosnt execute the script.

Any idea would be greatly apreciated thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Right now I have `ssh -t $USERNAME@$IP "su - && /home/$USERNAME/firstboot/firstboot.sh"` but it connects me as su - on the remote server but dosnt execute the script.

Fundamentally, you can't use `su` like that. Forget `ssh` for a moment; if you run `su - && date`, the `date` command will only execute *after* the `su` shell has exited (because `command1 && command2` means "run `command1` first, and if it exits successfully, run `command2`).

You need to use the `-c` option to `su` if you want to run a command in the `su` environment:

```
su - -c date
```

In your script, that means you want to run:

```
su - -c /home/$USERNAME/firstboot/firstboot.sh
```

So your ssh command should look like:

```
ssh -t $USERNAME@$IP su - -c /home/$USERNAME/firstboot/firstboot.sh
```

Comment: It was that simple? Juste adding -c? Wow hahaha well thanks a lot works like wonders!